# Probability of all services being done before you

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, queueing-theory

You are in a waiting room with $2$ people ahead of you. There are $4$ service desks with a service time that obeys an exponential distribution with a mean of $1$ hour. Currently all service desks are occupied.

What is the probability that all $6$ customers who arrived before you are also ready before you?

The time for all the $4$ customers currently in service to finish is $\exp(1)$ if I'm not mistaken. But beyond that I am fairly lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, for you to get some service, you need three customers to be ready and free up a desk for the two people and a desk for you. Once you start getting service, you are in a "competition" with the other 3 getting service.

Since the distribution is exponential and it is **memoryless**, it doesn't matter how much time everyone was getting service before that moment. From the moment you sat down, the service time of each of the customers follows an exponential dist. with parameter 1.

Due to symmetry, the probability that your service time will be the longest is $\tfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: So this means that if we add another person right behind me then  their probability of finishing ahead of me will also be $0.75$?

Comment: In that case, for him to finish ahead of you, he needs to get service while you still there. Then, each has $0.5$ chance of finishing before the other. For him to get service while you're getting it, he needs for you to not be the first to finish, which happens with probability $0.75$. So, for him to be ahead of you, the prob is $0.5\cdot 0.75$.